# Control UIWebView from the web page

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

How can I control the UIWebView in an iOS app from the web page?

For example, I want to resize it - not by setting the UIWebView's frame (in the Objective C code), but with some Javascript code, like window.resizeTo()

I've heard that I should implement a class that enables external control on the UIWebView.
Does anyone know which class is it?

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: Hi, thanks for those who replayed :) I'm actually looking for something that "calls" the UIWebView from the Javascript, not something that calls Javascript from the UIWebView. Does anyone know anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out lines 26-45 in this class.

https://github.com/trailbehind/Map-Chat/blob/master/Classes/ChatViewController.m

Is that what you are looking for?

I was using a UIWebView within a chat app. You can basically make a UIWebView do any JavaScript you want.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can look at:

- the UIWebView method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
- the UIWebView Delegate Protocol Reference, especially the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest method